# How to iterate Json object from JDBC Request In Jmeter

Tags: java, jdbc, jmeter

I have used JDBC Request in JMeter to get the data from the MySQL table. The select query returns a JSON object like below:

```
{"HeaderKey":"BR023159537221170209370","ReceiptSequenceNumber":"6643182852","status":"Success"}
```

[JDBC Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lb6b5.png)

I have to get the status key from the object. How I can achieve it using JDBC Request?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to [JDBC Request sampler documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) the result will be stored into `${IHM_response_3_1}` variable.

So you can extract the `status` from there using [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor) configured like:

[image]

Once done you should be able to refer extracted value as `${status}` where required

Comment: Thanks Dmitri T for the help I did the same changes and it did not work because the exact output of the query is [{Response={"HeaderKey":"BR02315953722113298579","ReceiptSequenceNumber":"6643183402","status":"Success"}}]  So I need to get this response in 1 variable and extract the value.

Comment: Move this `IHM_response_3` from the "Result Variable Name" to "Variable Names". More information: [Using JDBC Sampler in JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733769-Using-JDBC-Sampler-in-JMeter)